# English language parser in C (FLEX-LEXAR) working on sentence classification

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis, lexical

i am working on an english language parser which a sentence as input from the user and does 3 tasks.

1. Check if the sentence contains words from my defined rules in rules section(verbs,nouns,pronuns etc)
2. Tagging individual words as noun,verb,pronoun comparing with rules
3. doing sentence classification.

i have done the first two parts can someone guide me how to modify my program to accomplish the 3rd part in flex which is simple and easy to implement.My code is given below

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include<stdio.h>

%}
extern FILE * yyin;
%%

[\t ]+      /* ignore white space */ ;

is |
am |
are |
were |
was |
be |
being |
been |
do |
does |
did |
will |
would |
should |
can |
could |
has |
have |
had |
go      { printf("%s: is a verb\n", yytext); }


very |
simply |
gently |
quietly |
calmly |
angrily     { printf("%s: is an adverb\n", yytext); }



to |
from |
behind |
above |
below |
between |
below       { printf("%s: is a preposition\n", yytext); }

work |
play |
help |
loves |
runs    { printf("%s: is a noun\n", yytext); }

if |
then |
and |
but |
or      { printf("%s: is a conjunction\n", yytext); }

their |
my |
your |
his |
her |
its     { printf("%s: is an adjective\n", yytext); }

I |
you |
he |
she |
we |
they        { printf("%s: in a pronoun\n", yytext); }


[a-zA-Z]+ {
     printf("%s:  don't recognize, it's not a correct word\n", yytext);
    }

\&.|\n      { ECHO; /* normal default anyway */ }

%%

main()
{
    char fn[25];
    printf("Enter a file name ");
    gets(fn);
    yyin=fopen(fn,"r");
    yylex();


}
```

and please i only want solution in flex which is simple and easy to implement

Comment: What do you mean with "sentence classification"? (Sorry, I'm not a native speaker.) IMHO, your sample code just prints debug output. Next step should be to let it return tokens. Then, you have to make a grammar (something like a simplified English grammar) to define rules which tokens may occur in which sequence to form valid sentences. Based on this grammar you can develop a parser. The parser might be a _recursive descent parser_ (written e.g. in C or C++). Alternatively, you could do it with yacc or bison (the "brothers" of lex or flex).

Comment: Btw. I'm impressed about your chutzpa to indend writing a parser for a human language. Parser construction is difficult even for formal languages but human languages are even harder. Although, you are lucky to make it in Englisch. AFAIK it is even harder for German. That's why I'm always amused about (i.e. I never trust) the green lines in Word for Windows... (For non-MS-Office users: the green lines denote grammar errors...)